# Column-wide formatting changes with tabular

Tags: tables, formatting, columns

I must be doing something wrong, but I follow the example precisely (as precisely as someone could reasonably guarantee) and LaTeX yet refuses to compile the document:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}rl}

--- HELP ---
There is an illegal character in the argument of an array or tabular
environment, or in the second argument of a \multicolumn command.
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}rl}
  hi & bye
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner - it isn't even that complicated, but that's a really cool package!  While it has similar syntax, it could confuse someone who was *only* looking at TeX.SE.  This is something that can be (and was) solved by nitpicking through the LaTeX Wikibook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out - it *was* a pretty dumb mistake.

My [source](http://wiki.xelatex.org/doku.php?id=tabular_material#formatting_text_in_a_tabular) didn't mention you had to `\usepackage{array}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}rl}
  hi & bye
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

works as expected.